# Bitnami Ghost CMS aws instance Config file is not valid JSON issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ghost-blog

I am setting up ghost cms on aws for a client and hit a wall. I am using the bitnami image for setting this up. I haven't touched the config file that comes default in bitnami image. Ghost is not starting up and it's showing this error in the log

```
Debug Information:
OS: Debian GNU/Linux, v10
Node Version: v10.20.1
Ghost-CLI Version: 1.14.0
Environment: production
Command: 'ghost log'
An error occurred.
Message: 'Cannot read property 'join' of undefined'

Stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
    at instance.isRunning.then (/opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/lib/node_modules/ghost-cli/lib/commands/log.js:34:88)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it literally wasted hours of my life. And the problem was found. The reason was that in the config file the url of the blog was given as an IP address. But Ghost has said in it's setup documentation that this is likely to cause issues. So when I changed this to a URL instead of the IP address it was fixed. Hurraaay!!